# How to check if a substring's CONTEXT matches a regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number of input pairs to search within a text using JavaScript. Each pair consists of a short string (let's say `cc`) and the context it should be in (say`[^\d]cc[^\d]`). I want to locate the matches in the text, but it's not a simple as using `indexOf([^\d]cc[^\d])` because this doesn't take the substring as reference.

For example, if the text is `1cccd` I should get `2` as output, but `'1cccd'.indexOf([^\d]cc[^\d])` gives `1` because this is the position where it finds `[^\d]` (the start of the regular expression).

I had tried something like `'1cccd'.replace([^\d]cc[^\d], '$&').slice(i).indexOf('cc') == 0` (where `i` advances through the text), but this reports all instances of `cc` regardless of context.

I then tried to use capture groups from `match` to check the amount of characters on the left of the substring: `var tmp = '1cccd'.match(([^\d])cc[^\d]); return tmp.index+tmp[1].length;`. But I can't direct this to a search region because `match` doesn't take `lastIndex` from a regex. On the other hand, `exec` does take `lastIndex` in but it can't use capture groups. (EDIT: `exec` **can** use capture groups, as shown in the answer)

Using a `lookbehind` seemed like the answer, but JavaScript doesn't support these.

Is there a way to check if a substring at a given position is in a given context, as specified by a regex?

Comment: _“but `'1cccd'.indexOf([^\d]cc[^\d])` gives 1”_ - really? I get a syntax error only ... as I would have expected, since to my knowledge indexOf only takes a string argument. Where from did you get that it would take regular expressions? Is that inside a specific runtime enviroment, or …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach here would be to match *and* capture the target pattern, including the remainder of the string until the end.  Then, use `indexOf`, offset by the beginning marker character(s), to find the index of where the real match occurred.

```js
var input = "1cccd";
var regexp = /^.*([^\d])(cc[^\d].*)$/g;
var match = regexp.exec(input);
console.log(match[1]);

console.log(input.indexOf(match[2]));
```

The trick here is that `match[1]` contains the match along with everything else which follows.  So doing an `indexOf` lookup on the input using this should only ever resolve to one thing, namely the match.  I offset by 1, because we also captured a single non digit character before `cc`.  You may adjust this offset to match the number of marker characters before the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that offset is precisely the problem. The strings and regex above were just examples and, since they are input by the user, there's no way of predicting this value.

Comment: My answer still works even if everything is input by the user AFAIK.  Why wouldn't my answer work in this case?

Comment: Suppose the input regex is `[\d][^\d]cc[^\d]`, then the output would be 1 instead of 2, unless I update the offset by hand. Also, your code doesn't use the input substring `cc`.

Comment: Then just capture the substring and entire remaining string in a separate capture group.

Comment: I think you nailed it since `exec` **does** support capture groups (contrary to what I wrote above). I will update when I have tweaked your code to do all I want (need to figure out first how to prevent JS from parsing a string variable).

Comment: @死老外 Xie Xie ni :-)

Comment: @死老外 If you have your own answer, then you may post that.

Comment: Well, I give up on finding a way to make JS detect a user-input backslash (`.raw()` is useless here), so the final code relies on the user knowing to add an extra one to escape each backslash.

Comment: \@Tim It's basically your answer, just tweaked to find more than one instace in the text. I came here under the impression that `exec` could not use capture groups (forget where I read that) but then you pointed me in the right direction.